# How to organize this context properly in terms of files and where to redirect in the store method after storing?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

**Context:**

I have a createConference.blade.php file that presents a form to the user to create a new conference.

After the user creates the conference with success he should be redirected to an area to manage the conference. The layout of this area is equal for all the pages, it has a menu at left and a content area at right like:

[image]

So the only thing that changes in the layout is the area at the right of this menu that changes according to the link clicked in the left menu.

There is also a front end where is possible to user search conferences, register in conferences, login, register, edit his user account, list conferences where he registered, list conferences he created, etc.

**Doubt**

I'm with some doubts about how to structure this in terms of routes, folders an code, can you give a help on how to do this in a proper way?

I check some examples like cms where there are admins that can create posts and then that posts are presented in the frontend. In this systems, it seems that is usual to create an "admin" folder and then inside this folder create a folder "posts", "categories", etc, then inside "posts" there is the "create.blade.php, show.blade.php, index.blade.ph, edit.blade.php, delete.blade.php", the same for the other stuff(categories, etc). And so is possible also to create resource groups for posts, categories, etc.

But in this conference system seems different because a user can create multiple conferences and for each conference, he has access to this conference management area to manage only that specific conference.

Also in this management area where the user can manage the conference is possible not just edit the conference, delete the conference, and update the conference like the posts in the cms example. In the conference management example, in the management area, the user can edit the conference details (name, description, etc), but can also manage other things related to the conference like create registration types for that conference, edit registration types, list participants registered, etc.

So Im with some doubts about how to structure this context properly.

**Structure that I have for now:**

For now I have a createConference.blade.php in the resources folder, so "when user accesses "http://proj.test/createConference" there is the form:

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('conference.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

And I have the routes for  this like:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::post('/conference/store', [
        'uses' => 'ConferenceController@store',
        'as'   => 'conference.store'
    ]);
    Route::get('/createConference', [
        'uses' => 'ConferenceController@create',
        'as'   => 'conference.create'
    ]);

});
```

Then I have the store method and its working fine.

But after storing the conference I want to redirect the user to that area with the menu with management options at left and the content of each management page at right. But here I'm in doubt about where to redirect, how to organize the folders, the routes and the code for this.

I already have the layout of this conference management area that is equal for all the management pages:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
@include('partials.head')
<body>
@include('partials.header')
    <div class="sidebar-container">
        <nav id="sidebar">
        <!-- conference management options links -->
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="admin_content py-3">
     @yield('content') <!-- content of each accessed management page -->
    </div>
</div>
@include('partials.footer')
</body>
</html>
```

In this "@yield('content')" is to present the content of each conference management specific page accessed by the user (home page with some stats, edit conference, list participants, edit registration types, etc).

Store method without the redirect part:

```
public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'conference_name' => 'required|max:255|string',
                 ...
            ]);


            $conference = Conference::create([
                'nome' => $request->conference_name,
                ...
            ]);
            //return redirect()-> where to redirect?
        }
```

So do you know how to organize this context properly in terms of files and to where redirect in the store method after storing the conference (using mvc pattern)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all think about modular structure of application. It will be useful and easier to maintain when you develope it.

Here you have example: http://kamranahmed.info/blog/2015/12/03/creating-a-modular-application-in-laravel/

We want to get kind of this example:

```
app\
    Modules\
        Employee\
            Controllers\
            Models\
            Views\
            routes.php
        User\
            Controllers\
            Models\
            Views\
            routes.php
```

And directly to your question: after storing conference I would redirect to kind of conference list. I guess you need to create CRUD (create, read, update and delete)

Hope it help! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but redirect to something like a conference list is not what is necessary because the user should be redirected to something like a panel to manage that specific conference that he has created.